# How to build grammar in Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: win-universal-app, speech-recognition

Coming from a WPF background, I was trying to find a counterpart of `GrammarBuilder` (in `System.Speech.Recognition`) to implement **choices**, **repeat** and **priorities** in a Universal Windows app development. But it appears more things are different in `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` than I expected.

It appears **Grammar** is called **Contraint** in this `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` namespace, which makes sense. But as I look for the replacement for `GrammarBuilder` and `SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar`, the closest **Constraint** I can find is `SpeechRecognitionListConstraint`. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognitionlistconstraint.aspx) says there are **Commands** and **Probability**.

But, how can we add **choices** and **repeats** into the **Commands** (`string[]`)? Something like:

```
var builder = new GrammarBuilder();
builder.Append("What is the", 0, 1);
builder.Append("forecast for ");
builder.Append(dayChoices, 0, 3);
```

or in SRGS

```
<rule id="forecast">
<item repeat="0-1">What is the</item>
<item>forecast for</item>
<item repeat="1-">
    <one-of >
    <item>Monday</item>
    <item>Tuesday</item>
    <item>Wednesday</item>
    <item>Thursday</item>
    <item>Friday</item>
    <item>Saturday</item>
    <item>Sunday</item>
    </one-of>
</item>
</rule>
```

---

The [example code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cs/ListConstraintScenario.xaml.cs) in the demo app only has `string[]` as **commands**.

Comment: For srgs grammars you can use [SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognitiongrammarfileconstraint.aspx). Overall, you should not worry too much about repeats, list constraint should be as effective as grammars, just list all the words you are interested in.

Comment: What do you mean "just list all the words"? a string list of `{"forecast for Monday", "forecast for Tuesday", "forecast for ...}`?

Comment: Yes, a list of strings like that